# Rails active_storage: Check if an attachment is the same as a given file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checksum, rails-activestorage

Given the following situation:

- document `source` of type PDF freshly received via a file transfer
- document `target` which is saved as an attachment blob using `active_storage` and versionned

I want to check whether any existing version of `target` is binary-equal to `source`. Without `active_storage`, I'd have done a SHA256 sum of any blob that enters the DB. In order to compare, I'd have compared the fresh SHA256 sum of `source` to each checksum stored for any version of `target`.

However the method `.checksum` of `active_storage` attachments and blobs appears to be neither a MD5 or SHA265 sum. For instance I get `Cr4IxYNF7v7cJao1EiiBEw==` for some file.

A solution would be to use something like `Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(Person.find(46).photo.download)` however the performance would be terrible.

How can I efficiently search my `active_storage` "database" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ActiveStorage source, the checksum is in fact MD5. But it has been base64 encoded.

From the source at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8da6ba9cae21beae1ee3c379db7b7113d2731c9b/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L313

```
def compute_checksum_in_chunks(io)
  Digest::MD5.new.tap do |checksum|
    while chunk = io.read(5.megabytes)
      checksum << chunk
    end

    io.rewind
  end.base64digest
end
```

So hopefully you should be able to just base64 encode your own MD5 hashes for a comparison in the database.